# Adding Custom Ribbon to List Tools

Tags: 2010, development, ribbon

I Think I have tried every variation from all of the sources I can find, except for the correct one.  I want to add a ribbon button the the List Tools tab on lists.  Here is what I am doing:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

 <CustomAction

 Id="Ribbon.List.Actions.AddAButton"

 Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"

 RegistrationId="100"

 RegistrationType="List"

 Title="Add a Ribbon Button">

 <CommandUIExtension>

  <CommandUIDefinitions>

    <CommandUIDefinition

      Location="Ribbon.List.Actions.Controls._children">

      <Button Id="Ribbon.List.Actions.NewRibbonButton"

        Command="NewRibbonButtonCommand"

        Sequence="5"

        Image16by16="/_layouts/WPImages/excel.png"

        Image32by32="/_layouts/WPImages/excel.png"

        LabelText="Hello World"

        TemplateAlias="o1" />

    </CommandUIDefinition>

   </CommandUIDefinitions>

   <CommandUIHandlers>

    <CommandUIHandler

      Command="NewRibbonButtonCommand"

      CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world');" />

   </CommandUIHandlers>

   </CommandUIExtension>

   </CustomAction>

   <CustomAction Id="export.ScriptLink.jQuery"

     Location="ScriptLink"

     ScriptSrc="js/exportToExcel.js"

      Sequence="10010">

  </CustomAction>





  </Elements>
```

I am missing something small I know.  I just need a bit of help please.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I love it when 5 minutes later I figure it out.  Make sure for anyone who is also having this problem, check your RegistrationId to be sure it is pointing to the right list.  that was my mistake.  [Here is a link to a list of them.](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/sharepoint-registrationid-list-template.html)

Comment: And that only you could have figured out, since 100 is also a valid value :)